# How to access 2 different HTML files from 1 JS file?

Tags: javascript, html

I have two HTML pages and one JS file, which does the logic for both of them. When I try to change an image dynamically in one of my HTML files using `var mainImage = document.getElementById("lastImageID");` this works, but when I try to do the same thing for the other HTML file, it doesn't (I receive null as a result).

I have "included" `<script type="text/javascript" src="controller.js"></script>` the JS file in both HTML files.
I also tried to find information here, in Stack Overflow, how to access an element in an HTML file other than using the `document` notation, but seems this is the only right way.
I also checked and there are no identical IDs in both files.

First HTML file (relevant code):

```html
<div class="thumbnail">
  <img id="mainImageId" src="img/decision.jpg"
       alt="Decision">
</div>
<div class="textMessage">
  <div id="messageToUserID" class="infoText">   
    <h5>some text</h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

Second HTML file (relevant code):

```html
<div class="thumbnail">
  <img id="lastImageID"
       src="img/congratulations.jpg"
       alt="Decision">
</div>
<div class="textMessage">
  <div id="lastMessageToUserID" class="infoText">
    <h5>some text</h5>
</div>
```

JavaScript Code:

```js
// A function, which receives an new image, and updates the main image of the simulation by it.
function updateImageInLastScreen(newImage){
    var mainImage = document.getElementById("mainImageId");
    mainImage.src = newImage;
    var lastImage = document.getElementById("lastImageID");
    lastImage.src = newImage;
}


// A function, which receives an new message, and updates the main message of the simulation by it.
function updateMessageInLastScreen(newMessageToUser){
    var mainMessageToUser = document.getElementById("messageToUserID");
    messageToUserID.innerHTML = newMessageToUser;
    var lastMessageToUser = document.getElementById("lastMessageToUserID");
    lastMessageToUser.innerHTML = newMessageToUser;
}
```

The access to the elements in the first file work, but to those in the second one do not...

[Here are 4 small files I am working with](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0BwClCdVmEu2vODlNMEtUX0Z5Szg?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hi @Tay Yang Shun, thanks for the reply! The answer for your question is negative, and that is what I meant by writing "I also checked and the IDs of the elements are not identical".

Comment: It would help if you added the relevant bits of the two HTML files as well as the JS file to your question.

Comment: Hi @TayYangShun, done for your request. 10x!

Comment: @Felix Ignore my privious comment. How you want it to work ?, you are calling the updateImageInLastScreen() with an parameter and the document will get the current document the script is executed in and in the same function you use the document again hoping it will update the other document. Is this even possible ?  I guess with the <script> tag every html gets a copy of the script and it's not like a singleton channel that can operate.

Comment: @VinodSrivastav, thank you for your answer. I am not exactly sure I understand your response and the problem you described: I deliver an image to a function in a JS code, and I want this code to update an HTML file, that's it. No complications, it should work. It works for one HTML file and doesn't for another HTML file, and I am just trying to understand why.

Comment: @Felix My bad :(  i will update my answer soon and make it work for you

Comment: @VinodSrivastav, no worries, thank you for your time :). If you read Tay Yang Shun's answer below, you will see what was my mistake: I tried to access an HTML file, which was not yet created!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `if` checks before manipulating the content:

```js
// A function, which receives an new image, and updates the main image of the simulation by it.
function updateImageInLastScreen(newImage){
    var mainImage = document.getElementById("mainImageId");
    if (mainImage) {
        mainImage.src = newImage;
    }
    var lastImage = document.getElementById("lastImageID");
    if (lastImage) {
        lastImage.src = newImage;
    }
}


// A function, which receives an new message, and updates the main message of the simulation by it.
function updateMessageInLastScreen(newMessageToUser){
    var mainMessageToUser = document.getElementById("messageToUserID");
    if (mainMessageToUser) {
        messageToUserID.innerHTML = newMessageToUser;
    }
    var lastMessageToUser = document.getElementById("lastMessageToUserID");
    if (lastMessageToUser) {
        lastMessageToUser.innerHTML = newMessageToUser;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your comment! In general you are right. This would be a good practice, and I should add this to the code regardless to my problem, but my problem is exactly the fact that the lines before the `if` statements (that you suggest) return nulls. They shouldn't, and that is exactly what I am trying to understand!

Comment: I think you have a misunderstanding on how the browser operates on the HTML and JS. The browser only renders one HTML page at any one time within a window/tab, and the contents of the other HTML doesn't exist in the DOM.

Comment: thanks a LOT! I think THIS IS EXACTLY THE ANSWER! I am not new to coding, but new to HTML/JS/CSS, and I actually didn't realize that.OK then now, after understanding the issue, how would you suggest to approach the issue? I need to generate the content of `lastPage.html` dynamically, based on the state of my simulation: if the state is A then the image and the message should be fit this state, if the state is B then the image and the message should be fit this state, etc. Thanks!

Comment: @TayTangShun, thank you so much for your efforts, you are awesome. Yet please don't bother. I have solved this issue by just using 3 different HTML files for each end state, and that's it. All the very best! :)

Answer (score 0):

So...I dont understand very well. Tell me if my explanation is equal your problem.

I have created page1.html

```
<h1>Image 1</h1>
<img src="" alt="image one" style="width:304px;height:228px;" id="image1">
<script src="myfile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then, I have created page2.html

```
<h1>Image 2</h1>
<img src="" alt="image two" style="width:304px;height:228px;" id="image2">
<script src="myfile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

In myfile.js I put the one piece image

```
var image1 = document.getElementById('image1');
var image2 = document.getElementById('image2'); 

if( image1) image1.src = 'image.jpg';   

if( image2 ) image2.src = 'image.jpg';
```

This way is your problem ? Here, this way works both images.

Comment: Hi @joelton, thank you for you reply. I think you do understand my code, yet my problem is that for some reason I can't access the second file, which is the one that I need (I have implemented the rest just to check myself).
Translating my problem to your code would be that the line `var image2 = document.getElementById('image2');` will return null for some reason, which is unclear to me...

Comment: @Felix the flux has stopped because you must adding if checks. When you are in second file, in console screen appears any error ? like 'Cannot set property 'src' of null' ? I think if you control adding if checks, the flux works.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. You are right in your observation, but my problem is not the detection why the code doesn't continue running, but why the above lines (`var lastImage = document.getElementById("lastImageID");` and `var lastMessageToUser = document.getElementById("lastMessageToUserID");`) return nulls. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

when you call the same function `updateImageInLastScreen()` for the second html this line `var mainImage = document.getElementById("mainImageId");` gets the value as **null** (*since 'mainImageId' is not there in second html*) and the second statement after it `mainImage.src = newImage;` throws an exception saying

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null
>       at updateImageInLastScreen

and stops the further execution. You can verify the same in F12 console.

But when you call it from the first html then also it throws an exception for `lastImage.src = newImage;` but since it comes after the `mainImage` it's getting updated.

As per your code it's obvious that either of the element will be null since it's being called from a single html file. And you are blindly looking for the availability of the second element.

You can overcome this by putting your code inside a `try..catch` block as

```
function updateImageInLastScreen(newImage){
    try{
        var mainImage = document.getElementById("mainImageId");
        mainImage.src = newImage;
    }
    catch(e){
        console.log(e);
    }

    try{
        var lastImage = document.getElementById("lastImageID");
        lastImage.src = newImage;
    }
    catch(e){
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

you can find it working here https://jsfiddle.net/hk30k20t/1/